# Laravel 5.2 query builder insert method not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I´m using Laravel 5.2 and I`m using query builder for insert data

```
DB::table('table')->insert(['field1' => $data['data1'], 'field2' => $data['data2'], 'field3' => $data['data3']]);
```

this is the controller code

```
$model = new Model();
$data =  array( 'data1'=>$var1, 'data2'=>$var2, 'data3'=>$var3) );
$save = $model->save_data( $data );
```

I don`t have any errors but data is not saved in the db.

I use in the same model different method query builder methods like update and get and both works fine.

The table have auto increment id data1 is int, data2 is int and data3 is varchar(255)

the values in the array are parsed to the correct data type.

Comment: Print the raw query by using: 
`DB::enableQueryLog();
$queries = DB::getQueryLog();
print_r($queries);`

Answer (score 1):

I was making a mistake, the order of the columns of the table must be the same as the order of the insert, I assumed that since the array has the name of the field and its value, the order did not matter.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jorge! Gracias :) It has to be the same order and the same field names if you want to do the laravel INSERT query